# Как устанавливать темы bootstrap для rails

Tags: bootstrap, ruby-on-rails

Скачал тему для bootstrap и нигде не могу найти как их ставить в приложение на rails. Я так понимаю необходимоскопировать все файлы темы в какую-то папку приложения. Вопрос - в какую?

Comment: Вам лучше знать. Ваше приложение, вы организовывали систему ассетов. ...наверное.

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию в папке "public" необходимо создать папку "assets" и туда поместить все файлы скачанной темы.